# Need to design table with additional information about each column

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

How I should set up this SQL database. I am using SQLAlchemy with SQLite.

I have a table of data taken from several temperature sensors. Each column represents a sensor and each row corresponds to all the measurements taken at a particular DateTime.

I need to associate additional information about each sensor. Since the sensors are columns and not rows, I wasn’t sure what the best way to do this is.

```
Table 1. Nodes.
DateTime         |  HallwayTemp  | HallwayRelativeHumidity  |    CrawlspaceTemp    | ..etc
2011-01-08 22:05 |  20.10        |      46.5                |       25.12          |
2011-01-08 22:06 |  20.05        |      46.3                |       25.10          |



Table 2. Sensors
ID    |  Units   |  Sensor Type   |    VariableName(?)    | Location Description ..etc
1     |  C       |  TMP36         |    HallwayTemp        |2nd Floor Hallway Temperature
2     |  %       |  Hobo          |HallwayRelativeHumidity|2nd Floor Hallway Relative H.
```

I need to allow the user to add sensors to the database. If the user adds a sensor to the table I would add this sensor to the database table, then add that a column to the Nodes table with the VariableName as its title.

Is this the right way to go about this? is there a better way?

Comment: Seems fine to me if adding/removing columns is nothing that happens on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have a good design here at all. You do need two tables, but adding sensors as columns is a bad idea. You need to look into database normalisation. Here's how I would do it:

```
Sensor table             Log table
-------------            ------------------
id (primary key) ---+    id (primary key)
units               +--- sensor id (foreign key)
type                     datetime
location                 temp
```

This has nothing to do with presentation. you example above indicates that you are confusion database tables and rows with presentation of data. First get the data right. Then figure out how to display it. Querying the example I have will give you data like this:

```
st:id units type  location lt:datetime      temp
==========================================================
1     c     TMP36 Hallway  2010/01/01 22:05 15
1     c     TMP36 Hallway  2010/01/01 22:06 16
```

etc

Using reporting software you can take this and produce the grid you want.

Answer (score 1):

If i were in your shoes, i would consider a slight change especially in the Nodes table design

*Table 1. Nodes*

*Columns  :*

```
DateTime : Date + Time of the recording   
SensorID : Foreign Key to table:Sensors;column:ID
Value    : The value recorded by that specific sensor at that dateTime
```

This way, addition of a new Sensor does not involve any change to your table schema.
You can just keep adding records to *Nodes* with the new Sensor Id that has been added